# C# WPF Process getting StandardOutput is intermittent

Tags: c#, python, process

I have a Python Process running in my C# file for WPF:

```
        ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"python ", location);
        StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        try
        {
            p.StartInfo = StartInfo;
            p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
            p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
            p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(OnDataReceived);
            p.Exited += new EventHandler(OnProcessExit);
            p.Start();
            p.BeginOutputReadLine();
            p.BeginErrorReadLine();
         }
        catch (Exception exc)
        {
            Console.Write(exc);
        }
```

and later:

```
private void OnDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Data != null)
        {
            torOut = e.Data;
            Console.WriteLine(torOut);
        }
    }
```

My Python program has multiple messages printed a second. When I run this, only some of the output appears; for example, `print "message"` may be called 50 times, and only after the 50th time will all 50 messages appear as a batch.

Is there a problem with my approach, or is the rate at which StandardOutput is read particularly slow / intermittent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone has a similar issue, I eventually solved it. Add the following after any time output is needed:

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: There must be a way to this in a less verbose way - putting this line after every print line statement seems too much....anyone??